# My content positioning moves when I add text-shadow

Tags: html, css

How do I give my content a shadow? I have this code in the HEAD section;

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app2.css">
```

Whenever I add this code below;

```
text-shadow: 0px 4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.4),        
                 0px 8px 13px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
                 0px 18px 23px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
```

to this initial code below;

```
#content {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 25%
```

It sends my content from the middle of the page to the top and no shaddows get added. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: All the code you posted above looks fine, please provide a complete example with HTML & CSS which can reproduce the problem you describe above.

Comment: can your add your html code too?

Comment: You could try pasting your CSS code in to a CSS validator. It's possible you've missed a semicolon, closing bracket etc.... try here: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input

Comment: I took one more look at the code this morining and realized that yes, I missed a semicolon after 25%, thank you all for your help, this is a great tool for us beginners!